# What is the flaw in this C++ code?

Tags: c++

(I am a beginner to C++. But I am familiar with some other prog. languages, specially with Java.)

Can anyone please help me to find the flaw in this C++ code?

```
string & getFullName(string name, bool male){
    string fullName = name;
    if (male) {
        fullName = string(” Mr. ”) + fullName;
        return fullName;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're returning a reference to a local. You don't wanna do that.

Answer (score 10):

There are at least three problems:

- First, you're returning a reference to the local variable.
- Second, there is no `return` when `male` is `false`. I mean, what if the `if` block didn't get executed? What will your function return? There is no return statement for this case.
- Third, `“Mr. ”` is not a string literal. `"Mr. "`  is a string literal. Note the difference.

---

The fix can be this:

```
string  getFullName(string name, bool male)
{
    if (male) 
    {
        return string("Mr. ") + name;
    }
    else
    {
        return "Ms. " + name;  //No need to write even `string("Ms.")`
    }
}
```

No need of local variable.

Or simply:

```
string  getFullName(string name, bool male)
{
    return (male ? string("Mr. ") : string("Ms. "))  + name;
}
```

Comment: @Nawaz: Now you've brought up the endless style argument over whether the `else` belongs since the code above it always returns.

Comment: Great answer. @Kasnel That "Stack" thing. Go study about it and expand ;-). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Would you explain a lil bit more please?

Comment: @ai64: There's an endless argument over whether one should write `if (x) { foo(); return k; } else { return j; }` or `if (x) { foo(); return k; } return j;`. Since the `if` block always returns, the `else` serves no purpose. We'd only get past the `if` if we didn't return. But some people argue that it's better to have it even though it's not necessary and some argue that it's horrible to put it there.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: *Since the if block always returns, the else serves no purpose*. I think it enhances readability (at least to the new programmers) which could be `else`'s purpose in that case.

Comment: @Nawaz: I mean it serves no purpose in the execution of the code. Certainly those who argue it should be there believe it serves a purpose. And not that I disagree with you, but the obvious counter-argument would be that it reduces readability because when you see it, your first thought would be that its purpose was to affect the flow of the code, since that's an `else`'s normal purpose -- you have to figure out that it doesn't do anything to the flow.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: In your example you are right, but in the example of the topic starter, there is no return after the if statement, and that is the problem that Nawaz was pointing at.

Comment: @physicalattraction: That's why I said Nawaz brought it up.

Comment: The readability and understanding flow of control is most certainly improved by including an otherwise-unnecessary `else`, but it's not "horrible" to do this, as it does not make any difference to the compiled code.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a reference to a local variable. It ideally means fullName will die once the function getFullName returns, and if you try to assign it something like

```
string myName = getFullName("Adam",true);
```

`myName` will be garbage.

Answer (score 1):

Don't return a reference to local and remove the single left curly:

```
void makeFullName(string &name, bool male){
    if (male) /* remove the curly */
        name = string(“Mr. ”) + name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the **fullname** is limited to this function only, hence once this function ends or goes out of scope, **fullname** is removed from the stack. Therefore when you return the reference of **fullname**, you return the address of flushed up memory hence you will get garbage value.
The other problem is when the condition of **male** is false, you are not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something more like this:

```
std::string getFullName(string const &name, bool male) { 
    std::string ret = "Mr. ";
    if (male)
        return ret+name;
    return name;
}
```

Another possibility would also make it easier to add titles to females' names if you chose:

```
std::string getFullName(string const &name, bool male) { 
    static const std::string titles[] = {std::string(""), std::string("Mr. ")};

    return titles[male] + name;
}
```

If you do want a title added to women's names, just insert it in place of the empty string above.

Comment: tnx, but I need to tell you that I am a very beginner to C++. So actually I can't understand the code you've provided perfectly. What is this std::string means? & what is title[]? Is it an array?

Comment: @Kasnel: `std::string` is the standard C++ string type. It's what your `string` should refer to, but I've written out the full name. Yes, `titles` is an array.

Comment: So is it wrong if I write just as string instead of std::string?

Comment: @Kasnel: You *can* make that work by putting `using std::string;` (or `using namespace std;` before your code. The latter is generally considered at least somewhat objectionable though (more accurately, quite a few people hate it intensely).